# How to make an arraylist remotely accessible

Tags: java, arraylist, rmi

I have a project where I am using Java RMI to make objects remotely accessible to other objects. I need to make the following class remote:

```
public interface MarketBB extends Remote
{
   public ArrayList<CloudEntry> getMarketBB() throws RemoteException; 
   public void moveAMP(int fromCloud, int toCloud) throws RemoteException;
}
```

The problem that I have is that because the ArrayList is holding CloudEntry objects, when the getMarketBB method is called from another object, nothing is returned.

Is there a way of making the ArrayList of CloudEntry classes remotely accessible?

Here is the code for the CloudEntry class:

```
public class CloudEntryImpl implements CloudEntry {

    int cloudId;
    String cloudName;
    double speedGHz;
    double costPerGhzH;
    double commsCost;
    double commsTime;
    int noAMPs;

    //constructor, get and set methods for fields

}
```

And the CloudEntry interface:

```
public interface CloudEntry extends Remote {

    public void setNoAmps(int noAmps) throws RemoteException;

    public String getCloudName() throws RemoteException;

    public String getCloudDetails() throws RemoteException;

}
```

Comment: can u explain what do you mean by nothing is returned

Comment: Do you have the source code of CloudEntry ? Does the class CloudEntry implement Serializable ?

Comment: i have the source for CloudEntry and it implements an interface which extends remote. it basically just has a few fields and methods to get and set these fields. I'm not sure whether to upload the code as a comment or a new reply but i think it would make sence for me to upload the rest of the code

Comment: by nothing returned i mean: ` marketBB = (MarketBB)Naming.lookup(
          "rmi://localhost:1099/MarketBB"); cloudArray = (ArrayList<CloudEntry>) marketBB.getMarketBB();
       cloudData = (CloudEntry) cloudArray.get(0); ` throws an out of bounds exception even though I have put some elements into the array before it was bound to the registry.

Comment: you should edit the question and add the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CloudEntryImpl` is not serializable. Try changing it to:

```
public class CloudEntryImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements CloudEntry {
    //...
}
```

Comment: thanks. i will try this. i thought that by implementing CloudEntry that would make CloudEntryImpl serializable?

Answer (score 0):

getMarketBB() returns a copy of the ArrayList. You cannot have it return a "live" view of the list.

Instead I would suggest you provide methods which match what you are trying to do with the list.  IMHO This is best practice with or without RMI.

```
public void addCloudEntry(CloudEntry ce);
public CloudEntry getCloudEntry(int i);
```

Comment: i need to return the full list of entries in the array. from what i see there will that not only get 1? i suppose i could get them all individually...

Comment: You can get a full list, but it will get just a snapshot.